# How to update oracle row programatically in java when a record is fetched (Record fetch and update will be bulk)

Tags: sql, spring, oracle, spring-boot, scheduler

I am using Spring boot and Oracle.

I have a scheduler application which fetches record from DB based on scheduled time / validity time. Application fetches records from DB for each 30 seconds. It constantly looks into DB for below condition and will fetch data.

Condition: Current time >= scheduled time (or) Current time < validity time

(Please note: records in DB are not ordered).ie,I may have records scheduled on next month on top and records scheduled now may be available after first 100th record. So there is no order.

My problem is, based on my condition, records that have already been processed also is being fetched.

For ex:

- Record 1: Scheduled in next 10 mins, validity till next 10 days
- Record 2: Scheduled tomorrow, validity till next 10 days
- Record 3: Scheduled now, validity next 10 days.

My process should fetch only record 3 now. but due to OR condition, all the 3 records are fetched and being processed.

I tried processing only record 3 using it scheduled time and other conditions, but when processing after 10 mins, record 3 comes with record 1.

Is there a way to update the fetched and processed record in JAVA or Oracle or SQL?

I thought of using cursor, but cursor works in order. So no luck.

Please give an optimal solution to handle this as I may have hundreds of thousands of record to process in the same fashion.

Comment: If you don't want records that are not scheduled yet, why is there an **OR** and not **AND**? And if you want to process records just once, shouldn't you have a status field?

Comment: Those scheduled records may be approved on a later date . So i have to also check on validity date to process them . That's the reason I'm using OR instead of AND. I have a status field , but that won't do any good.

Comment: If you have a status field, why are you not excluding already processed rows?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use `select ... from ... for update skip locked`. In this case fetched rows will be locked because of `for update` and each select will skip locked rows.

Or you can also use `update ... where ... set status='processed' returning ... bulk collect into {collection}` in plsql and return(get) this collection to your java app.